# JSON returning 291 blank rows before data

Tags: json

I have created a JSON return using PHP (quite a few of them in fact) and the JSON is all valid according to JSONLint, and the data does work in my little iPhone app, but for every returned JSON feed I am getting 291 blank lines, the 1 line containing all the JSON data...

An example JSON return is :

```
{"EOF":"1","C":[{"T":"0 min","D":"0sec","MID":"","M":"","ML":"","C":"No comments"}]}
```

...with 291 blank rows before this... and by blank I mean completely blank, no spaces, no characters, absolutely nothing.

Has anyone else experienced this and, if so, how did you combat it?

**** UPDATE ****
Here is the code:

Basically it retrieves a result set from a MySQL database, and if nothing is returned it returns the JSON listed above... I get the blank 291 rows whether MySQL query returns data or not. For some items there are 1 or two rows in the database, and for other items there are over 500 items, and all data is returned and validated correctly.

```
$jsonDetails='{"EOF":"'.$EOF.'","C":[';
  while ($commentRow = mysql_fetch_row($allComments)) {
      $commentMakername=get_Username($commentRow[2]);
      $MakerLevel=get_UserLevel($commentRow[2]);
      $jsonDetails.='{';
      $jsonDetails.='"T":"'.strtolower($commentRow[3]).'",';                       $jsonDetails.='"D":"'.human_time_diff( $commentRow[5] ).'",';
      $jsonDetails.='"MID":"'.$commentRow[2].'",';
      $jsonDetails.='"M":"'.ucfirst($commentMakername).'",';
      $jsonDetails.='"ML":"'.$MakerLevel.'",';    $jsonDetails.='"C":"'.$commentRow[6].'"';
      $jsonDetails.='},';
  }
  if(strlen($jsonDetails)>=17){
  $jsonDetails=substr($jsonDetails,0,-1).']}';
  }else{$jsonDetails='{"EOF:"1","C":[{"T":"0 min","D":"0sec","MID":"","M":"","ML":"","C":"No comments"}]}';}
  return $jsonDetails;
```

Comment: Is there *any* reason why you create JSON in such an inappropriate way instead of using `json_encode()`? An the newlines are not added by the code you posted.

Comment: Hi ThiefMaster - I am doing it this way as the database contains much longer field names than I wish to deliver to a mobile client. So I manually create the json in this way to optimize the amount of data returned... I supposed I could add the variables to an array with appropriate associations and json-encode that... would that be more efficient?

Comment: or rename all columns in the database?

Comment: You can simply create a new array with different keys. Or use `col AS aliasname` in your query.

Comment: thank you - I will use col AS aliasname so I can simply json_encode the SQL return. Could the blank rows be due to my server configuration possibly?

Comment: The empty lines are very likely due to some of the functions you omitted (`get_Username`, `get_UserLevel`, `human_time_diff`) printing newlines.